# AngularJs directive with HTTP request data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to AngularJs, I have a problem using a custom directive when data comes from an HTTP request.

I have a service with an HTTP get request.

```
app.service('someService', function($http, $q){

    this.getData = function(){

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'theUrl'
        })
        .success(function(data, status){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            deferred.reject;
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }

})
```

and a controller that calls the service.

```
app.controller('someConroller', function($scope, someService){

    someService.getData().then(function(response){

        $scope.data = response;
    })

    $scope.someArrayData = [
                 {.....}, {.....}, ...
             ]
}
```

Here is a very simple custom directive.

```
app.directive('customDirective', function(){

    return {

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            console.log(scope[attrs['customDirective']]);
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is when I get an instance of the directive using `someArrayData` it works fine. But when I get an instance of the directive using `data` (the data that I get from the http service) console.log(data) gives me undefined.

```
<div custom-directive="someArrayData"></div><!-- console.log(scope[attrs['customDirective']]) gives the expected result -->

<div custom-directive="data"></div><!-- console.log(scope[attrs['customDirective']]) undefined -->
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does the HTTP response contain the data you expect in the format you expect?

Comment: Yes, it contains data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a `$watch` to "listen" for that new value inside your directive once resolved by your service. There are various ways to do this, but this will be the most straightforward for understanding the concept. Also, you can likely clean this up a bit if you bind your value to that directives scope - essentially your call to `scope[attrs[...` can be streamlined. Observe the following...

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    // -- simulate ajax call
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    }, 500)
})
.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=customDirective'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldValue) {
                console.log(newVal) // -- or console.log(scope.data)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jv30j6h0/) - demo

Comment: Thanks for answering, your solution should work, but it doesn't I don't know why. The solution proposed by @Mohamed ElSaqqa works.

Comment: remember to make the correct scope declaration with the `=`

Answer (score 3):

That's because the data is not yet retrieved when the directive is linked.
You can simply wrap the html element with ng-if:

```
<div ng-if="data">    
<div custom-directive="data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works fine, I don't understand why a watcher like proposed by @scniro doesn't work.

Comment: Solution by @BillBilal works just fine. His solution is based on watching the value attached to the directive scope and whenever it is changed you can fire whatever logic you want.

Answer (score -1):

The controller and the directive have different scopes, so when you assign `$scope.data` in your controller, you aren't doing it for your directive. So you should inject your service in your directive and request the data there.

If you are having trouble understanding scope heirarchies, read up on them in the [Angular documentation for scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

I would suggest downloading the [Angular JS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) extension for Chrome - it allows you to inspect all the different scopes on your page.

Comment: But {{data}} in the view binds the data.

Comment: That's because the view is bound to the controller - but the directive has a separate child scope. Try it!

Comment: I'll try it, but doing so, the custom directive will depend on the service and not on the data injected from the view. It is not reusable.

Comment: You are right, it's not re-usable. You might consider changing your design. If you want to use data from your controller, why did you make a separate directive? Also, check my edit about Batarang. Very helpful.

Comment: It's not the entire directive. I simplify it to show what is exactly my problem.

Comment: Btw all of the answers here are great answers. Whatever way you like is the best.

Comment: Why do you say "The controller and the directive have different scopes"?

Comment: @inorganik Thanks for the link to Batarang

Comment: @lukkea They don't have different scopes.

Comment: @lukkea They absolutely do have different scopes. Check out the documentation for scope heirarchies: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: We can't see the full implementation, and you could be right that they have different scopes looking solely at the code, but by inference from @BillBilal's question, the directive is declared within the controller and the directive doesn't explicitly declare a scope therefore it inherits from its parent (the controller).  But, maybe I'm missing something because you got an upvote...

Comment: @lukkea the fact that @BillBilal is asking why the scope properties don't match between controller and directive is proof they are different scopes. It's true they inherit though, another way Bill could've accessed it is to nest data in a parent object like `$scope.model.data` in both places.

Comment: I'm afraid "the fact that [they] don't match" isn't proof they are from different scopes (not least because they **are** on the same scope, as @BillBilal stated unequivocally after I posed my somewhat rhetorical initial question): The reason that they don't match is because of a race condition; see the currently accepted answer by scniro and Mohamed ElSaqqa's answer - the data hasn't come back from the server when the console.log call occurs.